# Can Anyone help me with Computer theory?

Tags: formal-languages

Hey guys I was given the following:

Consider the language S* where S = {aa, aaa}. Describe all the ways that a^12 can be written as the concatenation of factors in S.

I got 0 on this question even though it seemed pretty straight forward

Comment: Show us what you tried.

Comment: this is what i wrote aaa|aaa|aaa|aaa, aa|aa|aa|aa|aa|aa, aaa|aaa|aa|aa|aa,aaa|aa|aa|aa|aaa, aaa|aa|aaa|aa|aa, she says they are 12 combination

Answer (score 1):

I would interpreted it as in how many different ways can I reach 12 'a's.
Which would be 12 as you said:

one for only aa:

1. aa aa aa aa aa aa

one for only aaa

2. aaa aaa aaa aaa

and (5*4)/2 for two aaas

3. aa aa aa aaa aaa
4. aa aa aaa aa aaa
5. aa aaa aa aa aaa
6. aaa aa aa aa aaa
7. aa aa aaa aaa aa
8. aa aaa aa aaa aa
9. aaa aa aa aaa aa
10. aa aaa aaa aa aa
11. aaa aa aaa aa aa
12. aaa aaa aa aa aa

Comment: Thank you. correct! i was at 10 when you answered, did not know the order matter SMH :(. that was 8 big POINTS

Comment: is there a way you we can describe it orally without writing them all down?

Comment: There are 3 Sets of elements, because the aaa only come in pairs. And each set has a certain number of permutations: 1.only aa = 1 2. only aaa = 1 3. 2*aaa + 3*aa : Here are 5 options for placing the first aaa and remaining 4 options for placing the second aaa. The rest is filled with aa. Now everything is counted double because aaa and aaa are the same, so you have to divide by 2. Makes (5*4)/2 = 10 for the third set. All together: 1 + 1 + (5*4)/2 = 1+1+10 = 12